# Issue with LogMX Regular Expression Parser

Tags: regex, logparser, log-viewer, logmx

We are using LogMX log viewer to monitor our application logs, using a Regular Expression Parser.

Every time a log message contains the "-" character, LogMX doesn't parse the log event as expected.

For example, the following log event:

`[ERROR] | com.nsoft.gmonitor.Controller - File Loader - Error while loading file "C:\GMonitor\prefs.properties - Copy"`

Is parsed as:

- Emitter:  `com.nsoft.gmonitor.Controller - File Loader`
- Thread:  `Error while loading file "C:\GMonitor\prefs.properties`
- Message: `- Copy"`

Instead of:

- Emitter: `com.nsoft.gmonitor.Controller`
- Thread: `File Loader`
- Message: `Error while loading file "C:\GMonitor\prefs.properties- Copy"`

We are using the following regexp:

`\[(.*)\] \| (.*) - (.*) - (.*)`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this regexp instead:

`\[(.*)\] \| (.*?) - (.*?) - (.*)`

I just added a `?` character after `.*` for 'Emitter' and 'Thread' fields/groups.
This is a common regular-expression issue (not specific to LogMX):

- `.*` is called a *greedy* quantifier: it means that it will try to match the maximum number of characters
- `.*?` is called a *reluctant* quantifier: it means that it will try to match the minimum number of characters

You can read more about this in [JDK API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (search for 'greedy') or [LogMX docs](http://www.logmx.com/docs/regex-parsers.html#Ex2).

PS : if you don't want to use regular expressions to parse your logs in LogMX, you could  use its "Log4j/Logback pattern Parsers" instead: the pattern `[%p] | %c - %t - %m` will match your need, and is reluctant by default for all fields/groups by default.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your regex is greedy. Try adding `?` to your groups to avoid regex greedyness.

Take a look at this one:

```
\[.*\] .? (.*?) - (.*?) - (.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PovveAEjoeyUd_xm)

Here you can see the correct values stored on groups:

[image]